# benchmark to run against normal server and vmware

Tags: vmware-server, performance, benchmark

we are switching over to vmware for our server.  I want to make sure no performance is lost.  What type of benchmark can I run on the old server and the new vmware server to determine performance?

Comment: what tool can i use to benchmark?

Comment: what does your server do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a benchmark that fits your server usage. If it is a mailserver you should benchmark mail delivery. If its a fileserver you should benchmark io. If you use it for computations you should run one of those.

IMHO you will loose performance if your vmware server does not have more power...
If you want to have fun, try bonnie++.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wienczny](https://serverfault.com/users/10225/wienczny) states on like-for-like hardware you will lose some performance, depending on version of VMWare and usage type - should be between 5% and 20% unless it's VERY IO-bound.